# Is there a way to clear the connection pool for DbConnection?

Tags: c#, dbconnection

When I use `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`, there is a static method available:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ClearPool(connection);
```

Even `OleDbConnection` has (or had) a method:  `ReleaseObjectPool()`, that seemed to do about the same thing.

But I am using the base `DbConnection` and I cannot find an equivalent way to free connections/resources.  Is there a way?

Comment: *Why* do you want to clear the connection pool? This will *only* hurt performance. You can set a limit to the connection pool if you want, but unless you use *really* bad data access patterns (eg opening global connections but never closing them), there shouldn't be that many connection sin the pool

Comment: One of the possible connection types is Pervasive.SQL, which sits on top of an old file-based structure (Btrieve).  Attempting to delete a database after a connection has been used fails unless the pool is cleared.  At least, it's the only reliable way I have found to be able to delete it successfully.  Every connection made is being properly disposed, so it's just a quirk with Pervasive and its file handling, I think.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't (because each provider has its own DbConnectionFactory derived class) and it's usually managed as a singleton, not with static methods. That said then base class can't (and shouldn't) know about its implementations. The only way I can think about is - sadly - to _manually_ check for actual DbConnection type and call proper method...

Comment: You could disable connection pooling with `Pooling=False`. The main benefit of pooling is that you don't have to re-connect and authenticate to a server each time you want to run a query. This isn't much of a benefit with an embedded database

Comment: PS Btrieve! That's something I haven't heard in a looooong while

Comment: Just to add a use-case: Operations want a method that does this, to call from their monitoring tool after a SQL fail-over has occurred. Currently they need to cycle all application pools, but if this works the downtime can be significantly shorter. It's still a good idea to cycle the application pools afterwards, but that can be done without extra downtime when at least a few nodes can handle requests.

Answer (score 2):

There is no provider-agnostic connection pooling, although the ADO.NET providers supplied with the .NET platform itself do use shared code for it internal to `System.Data` ([`DbConnectionPool`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/ProviderBase/DbConnectionPool.cs)). Given a `DbConnection`, you have no way of knowing whether it comes from a pool at all. ADO.NET providers aren't required to pool connections, though of course most do for performance reasons. So the literal answer to your question is "no, you can't clear the pool for any given `DbConnection`, since it's not required to come from a pool".

You can, of course, test for the specific type of your `DbConnection` and invoke the provider-specific method, if there is one. Since you already know the provider you're having a problem with (Pervasive.SQL) *and* you know you have a provider-specific problem that requires (or seems to require) clearing the pool (which is definitely not something you want to do in general) this requirement to test the type doesn't seem too onerous.

If your client code already uses a generic `DbConnection` (or better yet `IDbConnection`) you could write wrappers that return connections with the required behavior, but that's potentially quite a bit of work due to the hierarchies involved (you may end up having to wrap things like `IDbCommand` as well just to make `Command.Connection = myConnection` work, that sort of thing). Just separating your data layer is probably easier.